# T-SQL Coalesce to contstruct a dynamic sql select statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

```
DECLARE @sumh VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT 
    @sumh = COALESCE(@sumh+Name+']) AS ['+Name+'],SUM([' ,'') 
FROM
    Hals

SELECT 
    @sumh = 'SUM(['+@sumh+ ']) AS Sum'

SET @sql = '

SELECT 
    Category = ISNULL(CATEGORY,''Total''),CatID,'+@sumh+' 
FROM
    (--My Pivot Query Here
    ) AS P 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((CATEGORY,CatID),())'

PRINT (@sql)
```

Is producing

```
SELECT 
    Category = ISNULL(CATEGORY,'Total'),CatID,SUM([Bc-Def]) AS [Bc-Def],SUM([Cd-Def]) AS [Cd-Def],SUM([De-Efg]) AS [De-Efg],SUM([Ef-Fgh]) AS [Ef-Fgh],SUM([Fg-Ghi]) AS [Fg-Ghi],SUM([]) AS Sum  FROM
(--My Pivot Query Here
) AS P 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((CATEGORY,CatID),())
```

I have two issues as you might have noticed. The first row ('Name') from the table 'Hals' is ignored by the Coalesce And also, Any way I can get rid of the final "SUM([]) AS Sum"

To make it clear I want it to return as follows

```
SELECT Category=ISNULL(CATEGORY,'Total'),CatID,SUM([Ab-Bcd]) AS [Ab-Bcd],SUM([Bc-Def]) AS [Bc-Def],SUM([Cd-Def]) AS [Cd-Def],SUM([De-Efg]) AS [De-Efg],SUM([Ef-Fgh]) AS [Ef-Fgh],SUM([Fg-Ghi]) AS [Fg-Ghi]  FROM
(--My Pivot Query Here
) AS P 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((CATEGORY,CatID),())
```

I have a sql fiddle here to make it clear http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7d29/3
I am open to alternative solutions. (The column category and category id is returned from my pivot query and is tested working fine when i pass in test column names manually. I just need help to construct a dynamic select only.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
DECLARE @sumh VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SumH = ''
SELECT @sumh = COALESCE(@sumh+' SUM([' + Name+']) AS ['+Name+'] ', ' -- SHOULD NEVER OCCUR -- ') 
FROM Hals

SET @sql = '
SELECT Category=ISNULL(CATEGORY,''Total''),CatID '+@sumh+' FROM
(
--My Pivot Query Here
) AS P 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((CATEGORY,CatID),())
'
select @sql
```

When @SumH is never null, it will wlays take the first paramater in COEALESCE so then you could make the code much clearer to your intent, at least as i understood it.

Comment: This fine except for the commas in between.. I fixed it like this and adjusted the last comma by removing it from the following Select parameter. SELECT @sumh = COALESCE(@sumh+' SUM([' + Name+']) AS ['+Name+'], ', '  Thanks